# How to pick a value that exists only between range of data entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database containing specific dates data like:

```
Date                 Event
----------------------------------
1st January 1980:    Time of the Moon
21st January 1980:   Celebration of Columbus
12th February 1980:  Funeral of the Sun
```

I want to be able to query the database with:

> *select where day = 14, Month = January, and Year = 1980*

Wherefore, the result should be: **Time of the Moon**

My problem is, since the data being selected doesn't exist, how do I achieve the above query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Event 
FROM MyTable
WHERE date(`Date`) <= '1980-01-14'
ORDER BY `Date` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Would this work even if the dates are separated by say, 1 day? Also, I take it, I am actually using the `datetime` data type.

Comment: The `<=` asserts that the day itself is preferable, the `desc` sort asserts you get the first possible match (ie. the current or most recent date), the `limit` asserts there is only a single result. And yes, the `date` call extracts the date part of a `datetime` value, thus eliminating time from having a possible effect.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I wanted to include time (for instance 8am), I assume I'd follow the same concept? Timestamp maybe?

Comment: Just remove the `date` call and add the time to the comparison string in ISO format (`yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`).